# How to connect two view controllers with one button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have one button in main screen. When user clicks "Search" button, I will search that user in database whether he signed in or not.

If he already signed in, I will show "Sign Out" screen. If not, I want to show "Sign In" screen.

I connected "Search" button and "Sign In" view controller with push segue because I want to pass some data from main screen.

I tried to connect "Sign Out" view controller with "Search" button as well but I couldn't connect them.

How could I connect two view controllers with one button?

Yeah, with push segue and want to pass some values too. Now I use `prepareForSegue` method to pass data. Could anybody help me please? (If my question is too basic for you, I'm really sorry for that because I'm still a starter for iOS development.)

Thanks in advance!

[image: my sample design]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using code -

1. Create IBAction method for Search Button UIControlEventTouchUpInside event.
2. Now check user SignIn or SignOut within IBAction method and push respective viewController using below code

> ```
>  SignINViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignINViewController"];
>         [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
> ```

Don't forgot to provide Storyboard ID & Restoration ID for your viewControler from storyboard.

Comment: Yup, I have IBAction method and tried it once too. But my instantiation way is different from yours. I will try this way as well. Thank you :)